# My git commit is listed as by another author?

Tags: git, github

I've created a new profile on github. by username 'surajsun22'.

I quickly followed some tutorials online to commit changes using command line.

But the problem is the commit listed online doesn't match with my username. [image]

You can see it states updated by 'Surajpal2908'. but I don't know where it picked up that username

I used command 'git push' then it asked my github username and password.

It should list commit by my username but it didn't. Are there any reasons for that?

I'm on ubuntu 16.10

Comment: What email address did you use on your commit? That's how it identifies users. You should use an email address that you have claimed and verified on Github.

Comment: Are you doing git commit from any server or from your local ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to commit from a server which has its author set to a different user, hence it is showing you a different user in commit logs.

To change the author of your previous commit, just checkout to that commit

```
git checkout <commit id>
```

Change the author for that commit using

```
git commit --amend --author "New Author Name <New Author Email>"
```

Replace old commit

```
git replace <old commit id> <new commit id>
```

Finally, Push

```
git push -f
```

Or if you are doing it locally, just check the config.

You can set your config for that repo using

```
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.email "Your email"
```

or you can use below command while committing

```
git -c "user.name=Your Name" -c "user.email=Your email" commit ...
```